# NPM - tcp-ping is not transferring data on a global variable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For some reason the package tcp-ping isn't transferring data to a glboal variable, will someone help me with this problem please. Is there any way around this?

```
    var containerip = [];
    const clients = require('../../clients.json');
    var cl = clients['clients'];
    for (var keys in clients['clients']) {
        containerip.push(cl[keys].usr.ip);
    }
    var a = 0;
    var msg = "";
    var dat = "";
    var compose = "";
    var Embed = [];
    containerip.forEach(function (host) {
        tcpp.ping({ address: host, attempts: 3, port: 80, timeout: 1000 }, function (err, data) {
            if (isNaN(data.avg)) {
                var cname = cl[a].usr.name;
                compose = compose + '\n:desktop: **' + cname + '** → ❌  "Unable to reach client" '
            }
            else {
                var cname = cl[a].usr.name;
                compose = compose + "\n:desktop: **" + cname + "** → ✅  " + Math.round(data.avg) + " ms"
            }
            Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription(compose)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: 'Rocket Host Philippines', iconURL: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1029991101081325580/1031234620227858482/1.PNG?width=603&height=603' });
                client.channels.fetch('1032382346655174708').then(channel=>channel.send({ embeds: [Embed] }));
            a = a + 1;
        });
    });
```

It would be great if someone will help me with this been trying to solve this problem a couple of days now but i couldn't find a solution. And also by the way i try to push it on an Array which it didnt worl also.

Thank you very much!

Comment: in `containerip.forEach()` you set up pings to happen sometime in the future. Then with `client.channels` you try to access the global variable that hasn't been set yet. Look at `await Promise.all()` to solve your problem.

Comment: @some i forgot that i already set the global variable before that loop. I also dont get the line you've said 'Look at await Promise.all() to solve your problem. '

Comment: Also could you provide me an example dear sir.